# Hardcoded static IP assignment for eth1

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, ifconfig, nat

I'm setting up a NAT, and need to assign a static IP to my eth1 interface. The problem is that once in a while, it resets, and I need to run the following command again:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.47.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I was wondering if I can hardcode this static IP to this interface. Probably there should be a file which we would just need to modify, or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, you can use [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) to configure the static IP address.  For Ubuntu server (or manual configuration on Ubuntu Desktop), you can edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And add the following content:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.47.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You can apply the settings by restarting the networking service:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: I've done this, and unfortunately after restarting, ubuntu failed to show networks! look at here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213614/waiting-for-network-configuration-problem

Comment: @TinaJ did you solve this?

Comment: It was a long time back. I don't remember.