# Ubuntu 14.04 Server Startup just on WLAN

Tags: networking

For some technical reasons, I need to have Ubuntu 14.04 Server started just with WLAN.

That means, no Ethernet start up.

If I do so, it always takes some more time on the start up. I mean this "Waiting for 60 seconds ..." dialogue, if there is no Ethernet-cable plugged into the server.

Is there a possibility to suppress this dialogue and make Ubuntu start quicker?

Comment: I think, you can find an answer here:
[“waiting for network configuration” Problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213614/waiting-for-network-configuration-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to not start eth0 automatically. For example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid <your_network>
wpa-psk <your_secret_password>
```

By commenting out 'auto eth0', you tell the system to not start eth0 automatically.

Comment: Thank you chili555! This helped me! Sorry, that i gave you such a belated answer. Sometimes the WLAN is breaking its connection. I use wicd network-manager to cope this problem, but it is breaking once again. Is there a better possibility to stablize the WLAN-Connection? Greetings BornToFlyBert

Comment: That's a different question which I suggest you post. Include the wireless driver from either `lsmod` or `lshw -C network`. If my answer above has been helpful, please accept it.