# Ubuntu is 'Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...' on boot

Tags: boot, networking, plymouth

On boot, after I enter my full disk encryption password, I see Ubuntu display the following message (I believe that's a package called `Plymouth`):

> Waiting for network configuration...

then

> Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...

then the boot proceeds as normal.

Indeed, this happens when the computer doesn't have network connectivity, but why would it need network before booting to desktop? I don't want my computer to send or receive any information yet.

I am roughly following the guide [Quickly Setting up Awesome with Gnome](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome) for GNOME <3, but try to do it with a MATE desktop and Awesome.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from netinst `mini.iso` image, chose 'Install a command-line system' and proceeded installing with mostly default options, but chose encrypted LVM partitioning. Then I have installed MATE desktop environment with

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common # need them for 'apt-add-repository'
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg mate-core
```

I am starting desktop environment manually, with `startx` command; the delay appears before that and before I get the chance to log in with my user account. I have a wired network which works, when the cable is connected; otherwise, this strange notification appears.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/213614/waiting-for-network-configuration-problem