# After upgrading packages, network has gone

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 14.04 box, which was powered off for several months. I have turned it on, it worked, also network worked and I foolish ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

This caused my system has no network anymore. During boot, it displays messages from this ["waiting for network configuration" Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213614/waiting-for-network-configuration-problem) question. The solution from this question (strange one) does not work for me. I mean, if I remove `eth0` from `/etc/netwrok/interfaces` then error message disappears but network doesn't appear.

Machine has two network devices, which are marked `UNCLAIMED` by `sudo lshw -C network`.

How to fix?

**UDPATE**

I have read that this may be related with glitching `network-manager` and uninstalled it (it was installed) - this didn't help.

`ifconfig` shows only loopback interface.

**UDPATE 2**

`sudo ifup eth0` says

```
Cannot find device "eth0"
Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
Failed to bring eth0 up eth0
```

**UPDATE 3**

Configuring `eth0` as static didn't help.

Comment: Are you asking about a wire or wireless network?

Comment: And all is unclear. Is it a server, why network is configured without NM? What does `ifconfig` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 network is wired, both cards are wired. I don't know if it is server, but it loads w/o GUI. I would prefer it was headless machine.

Comment: Will you update your question and show the output of `ifconfig`?  By the way, NetworkManager would not have been the reason for your network to stop working.  It will ignore the interfaces that you have manually configured.

Comment: UNCLAIMED typically means that there is no driver associated with the device. Please edit your question to include: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: @chili555 too late, I have reinstalled it completely. Don't unserstand, why driver should disappear on upgrade.

Comment: I don't understand either, but the logs and clues needed to find and correct the issue are now gone. I assume all is well now. Enjoy!